# use relative clause or objective clause

Tags: relative-clauses, exam-questions

> It’s a humble landmark named for a man who tirelessly explored, documented, and fought to protect_____would become the most visited national park in the United States.

Filling "what" into the blank that I know would make sense, but why can't I insert "it, which" to make it a relative clause?

Comment: It wouldn't work. You can't modify "it" with a relative clause here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **it** here but you would need to divide the statement into two separate parts and either repeat **it** or find another subject for the second part.

> It’s a humble landmark named for a man who tirelessly explored, documented, and fought to protect it. It (the area / park)  would become the most visited national park in the United States.

This construction is much lengthier and repetitive.

It's much simpler just to use **what**, which here acts as a pronoun signifying **something that**. The choice of **it** does not serve the same function.

Comment: I mean why I can't write it like " It’s a humble landmark named for a man who tirelessly explored, documented, and fought to protect it, which would become the most visited national park in the United States" by using a relative clause ?

Comment: The construction requires a full stop / period or a semi-colon after **it** and a second statement to follow. The alternative is to write **....to protect something that would become.....**

Comment: Could you explain the grammar here and why my making it a relative clause is not right?

Comment: It's not clear what **which** relates to. I can only refer you to sites that illustrate the use of relative pronouns, such as: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/relative-pronouns-and-relative-clauses

Comment: I think "which" relates to "it" before the comma, but yeah, I will visit the sites